# Page not found showing when I click on Previw Button with a Js code in the post area

Tags: wordpress

In my WordPress website, I am writing a blog with this code

```
<button type="button" onclick="getData()">Get Data</button>
```

now when I press on the preview button then the theme is showing me **Page Not Found** error. Very strange!

If I write

```
<button type="button">Get Data</button>
```

Then preview mode is working fine!.

Can you tell me where the issues can be?

**Note:**

1) I am using Newspaper 8 Theme.
2) To insert the code I am using Enlighter WordPress Plugin